# What is the first film to show characters watching a film?

Tags: first-appearance, cinema-history

I’ve found many lists and supercuts of movie characters watching movies. I’m wondering what the *first* known instance of this (movie characters watching a movie) is.

Comment: Interesting question. IMDB has a keyword, "Watching a movie", and if you [list films with that keyword by release date](https://www.imdb.com/search/keyword/?keywords=watching-a-movie&ref_=ttkw_kw_242&sort=release_date,asc&mode=detail&page=1) it's a Japanese comedy from 1932 called [I Was Born, But...](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0023634/?ref_=kw_li_tt). Then many more in late 30s and 40s.

Comment: Voting to reopen as per the [meta] posts: [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006) and [Can we please redefine "trivia"?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1809/1006)

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 Could you turn that into an answer? It's a good start :)

Answer (score 4):

It's such an old trope that I don't know for certain what the first is, but the earliest one I can cite is [*Those Awful Hats*,](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0001062/) a 1909 Biograph comedy short in which women enter a movie theater wearing increasingly larger and more preposterous hats, blocking the views of the other patrons, until a big crane drops down from above and snatches one of the women away.